# How to make Headset work correctly?

Tags: java, comparator, treeset

I have this class:

```
public class Person implements{
private String name;
private int height;
...
}
```

People are compared by height. It seems reasonable to expect a situation where two different people can have same height. That's why I wrote this Comparator:

```
public static class Compar implements Comparator<Person> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        int r = Integer.compare(o1.height, o2.height);
        return r == 0 ? o1.name.compareTo(o2.name) : r;
    }
}
```

And this is my main:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    TreeSet<Person> ps = new TreeSet<>(new Compar());
    ps.add(new Person("Ann", 150));
    ps.add(new Person("Jane", 150));
    ps.add(new Person("John", 180));
    System.out.println(ps);
}
```

I got this result: Ann, height = 150 Jane, height = 150 John, height = 180. But when I want to use method `headSet`, I expect the next result: Ann, height = 150 Jane, height = 150, nothing appears in tr2.

```
TreeSet<Person> tr2 = new TreeSet<Person>(new Compar());
Person p = new Person("",150);
tr2 = (TreeSet<Person>) ps.headSet(p,true);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This looks like a "read the docs" type question. Have you read the TreeSet API? If so, what about the headSet method is confusing you?

Comment: I read about TreeSet and method headSet, I understand that it returns values which are strictly less but there is method public SortedSet<E> headSet(E toElement, boolean inclusive) which can return not strict values. I don't understand how to override comparator so that this variant of headSet will work

Comment: You don't change the Comparator -- it's fine. But in the future (or even now) please do post well-formatted code. Please remember that you're asking volunteers for help, and anything you can do that will make it easier for others to understand your code is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, nothing will appear in `tr2` since `.headSet()` returns a view of the portion of this set whose elements are strictly **less** than `p` (exclusive).

All of your other `Person` objects are equal/higher than `p` (150, 150, 180). If they are equal you compare them by their `name` field via your comparator (since you passed `true` as a second parameter to `.headSet()`. Since `p`'s `name` is an empty string it is less than the other names and therefore not included.

Documentation of this is [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/treeset_headset.htm), and I think you are looking for [`.tailSet()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/treeset_tailset.htm) instead.

Comment: I read about TreeSet and method headSet, I understand that it returns values which are strictly less but there is method public SortedSet<E> headSet(E toElement, boolean inclusive) which can return not strict values. I don't understand how to override comparator so that this variant of headSet will work

Comment: No? It gives Ann, height = 150 Jane, height = 150 John, height = 180? but I need only Ann, height = 150 Jane, height = 150

Comment: Oh, I'm wrong. tr2 = (TreeSet<Person>) ps.headSet(p,true); returns Ann, height = 150 Jane, height = 150 John, height = 180/ Your variant returns nothing

Comment: Your comparator compares by *name* if the Height is the same. That is why you can't do anything about it in headSet() if the Height is the same. If you do this your result will be as you wish: Person p = new Person("abcde",150);

Comment: Unfortunately, this variant didn't help

Comment: Thank you so much, the variant Person p = new Person("abcde",150) works! The problem was that when I ran project, it wasn't saved. Therefore I couldn't see changes.